Fail to install updates on Linux KDE:: libkcolorpicker-qt6-0 failed to install
SYMPTOM
Error message : Package failed to install: Error while installing package: trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkColorPicker.so.0', which is also in package libkcolorpicker0
STEPS TO REPRODUCE

Open discover.
Click 'Update'.
Click 'Update All'


Remove one of the mentioned package.

Here the solution worked for me

sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq libkcolorpicker0
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo pkcon refresh && sudo pkcon update

